# Check if list object is contained within another list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, list

I hope I'm phrased the title right- Overview: I'm trying to create a input check box.  I want to display all items & check the ones that are supposed to be checked by a list compare.  Here is my 'broken' code & where I'm going with this:

```
List<ConsolStand> csr = ConsolStand.GetConsolStands();
List<PackUserSecurityGroup> sg = PackUserSecurityGroup.GetPackUserSecurityGroup(0, iGroupID);

foreach (ConsolStand a in csr)
{
    if (sg.Contains(a.CsrID))
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@("routeDesc_" + a.CsrDesc)" checked="checked" /> @a.CsrDesc <br />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="checkbox" id="@("routeDesc_" + a.CsrDesc)" /> @a.CsrDesc <br />
    }
}
```

PackSecurityGroup is just one list object (it will return one column of ints), I'm trying to compare that list with the CsrID column in the ConsolStand list.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like this:

    List<PackUserSecurityGroup> sg = PackUserSecurityGroup.GetPackUserSecurityGroup(0, iGroupID);

...should be this:

    List<int> sg = PackUserSecurityGroup.GetPackUserSecurityGroup(0, iGroupID);

...which would make a lot more sense re: the rest of your code. Could you give a description of what's not working? Is nothing getting checked or is the page crapping out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying that your PackUserSecurityGroup has some ID property that you want to compare to? In that case you could add change this:

```
sg.Contains(a.CsrID)
```

to

```
sg.Any(s => s.ID == a.CsrID)
```

(make sure you have a "using System.Linq" statement as well). However, it would be more efficient to replace your sg list with either a Dictionary where the key is the ID, or just a sorted list of IDs.

Comment: Perfect!  The reason I've got it as a list, was my original SG List Class had additional columns in it which I removed in an attempt to get those two ID fields to match up.